# Syntax looping issue with Dos batch file no execution

Tags: batch-file, execution

This is what I have I'm trying to execute some basic file operations but the code cmd prompt just loops without any execution of activity or launching of either programs.

```
:loop
if not exist C:\Scanned\1.pdf GOTO LOOP
if exist C:\Scanned\1.pdf GOTO command
:command
if exist C:\Program Files\Microsoft\outlook.exe START outlook.exe /c /a C:\Scanned\1.pdf MOVE /Y C:\Scanned\1.pdf C:\Recieved
if exist C:\Program Files\"Mozilla Thunderbird"\thunderbird.exe START thunderbird.exe -compose attachment= C:\Scanned\1.pdf MOVE /Y C:\Scanned\1.pdf C:\Recieved
GOTO LOOP
```

Comment: a hot loop like this is not a very good idea, it will uselessly burn a lot of CPU. maybe consider inserting a delay after :loop, like `timeout 10 /NOBREAK`to wait 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
:loop
    if not exist "C:\Scanned\1.pdf" GOTO LOOP

    if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\outlook.exe" (
        echo here the outlook sending code
    ) else if exist "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" (
        echo here the thunderbird sending code
    )

    move /y "c:\scanned\1.pdf" "c:\received"
    goto LOOP
```

As a general rule Files/Paths with spaces MUST be quoted.